# Virtus : how to override a setter method on an attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for an equivalent of ActiveRecord write_attribute method in Virtus (https://github.com/solnic/virtus).

When trying to use attributes = { ... } it makes a stack level too deep exception as it tries to use the overridden setter method...

I would like to overwrite a setter to add some formatting.

for example I would like to convert this Active Record code in Virtus :

```
def phone_number=(number)
  write_attribute(:phone_number, number.strip.gsub(/[-\.\ ]/, ""))
end
```

Comment: Have you tried using super?

Comment: @BroiSatse : you're right, super is working right :)...

Comment: @BroiSatse can you post a quick example? I can't get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: @Hendrik - For the above it would be `def phone_number=(number); super(number.strip.gsub(/-\.\ ]/, '')); end;`. If this does not work for you, please write a new question stating what you have and what an error is.